# Error trying to do a GridSearchCV()

Tags: scikit-learn

On the following lines of code I am getting

```
clf = neural_network.MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 12))
parameters =[ {'solver': ['lbfgs'],'max_iter': [500,1000,1500], 'alpha': [1e-1,1e-2,1e-3,1e-4,1e-5,1e-6,1e-7],  'random_state':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}]
model = GridSearchCV(clf,param_grid=parameters,n_jobs=-1)
```

On the last line I am getting the following error

```
ValueError: Parameter values for parameter (solver) need to be a sequence(but not a string) or np.ndarray.
```

now I know from reading

[Parameters in GridSearchCV in scikit-learn](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13410/parameters-in-gridsearchcv-in-scikit-learn/13449)

That this means everything must be in an array but all my params are in an array so what am I doing wrong.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't get that (or any) error (after correcting your `paramators` to `parameters`).

That said, if you only want to use one solver, you might as well pass it directly to the estimator and leave it out of the grid search.

Answer (score 0):

No, Not all of your parameters are array, as pointed in the error message, the parameter "solver" is a list with a single string value.

You have declared {'solver' : ['lbfgs'] }, this is a list with a single string 'lbfgs'.

Parameter 'solver' should have list of values separated by comma, but you given only one value 'lbfgs'.

### For Example

You could change the parameter like {'solver' : ['l','b','f','g','s'] }, this is a list of string values.

#### Or

You could change the parameter like {'solver' : ['lbf','gs', 'abc'] }, this is also a list of string values.